# Get day numbers of a week number

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my application I store activities with a `day_number` ranging from 1 to 31 and a number of `hours`. Any activity belongs to a `timesheet` which contains a `month` and `year`.

Now I want to have an overview with all the weeks in a year and with the total number of activity hours in that week. I determine the weeks of a month with:

```
first_week = Date.new(timesheet.year,timesheet.month,1).strftime("%U").to_i
last_week = Date.new(timesheet.year,timesheet.month,1).end_of_month.strftime("%U").to_i
weeknrs = (first_week..last_week).to_a
weeknrs.each do |weeknr|
  # Do something
end
```

How can I determine the day numbers belonging to a specific week?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use the [week-of-month](https://github.com/sachin87/week-of-month) gem, which gives me a `week_split` method which returns an array with all weeks of a month and for each week all days: `Date.new(2012,1,1).week_split` returns:

```
 [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
    [15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21],
    [22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28],
    [29, 30, 31]]
```

Now I can easily iterate this array and query for activities:

```
- weeks = Date.new(year,month,1).week_split
- weeks.each do |week|
  - activities = Activity.where("month = ? AND year = ? AND day IN (?)", timesheet.month, timesheet.year, week)
```

Answer (score 5):

Please try this

```
1..7.each do |i|
 Date.commercial(timesheet.year, weeknr, i)
end
```

For more references,look at once

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-commercial

Hope, this will help you.

Comment: Thanks, but that would miss activities with day numbers between 8 and 31.

Comment: By putting above logic into your "weeknrs" loop. you will get all day between    first_week to last week.  Ex. Date.commercial(2016, 1, 1) where 2016 is year, middle 1 represent week, and last 1 represent monday.

Comment: Ah, now I understand what you mean, I missed the specific commercial method.